# Is there any other way to call a javascript function stored in mongodb from node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, eval

Is there any other way to call a JavaScript function stored in MongoDB from node.js other than `db.eval()`?

Tried `db.eval()` since its degrading my server performance, I'm have to use some other methods to invoke the JavaScript functions

Answer (score 0):

Try including jQuery and comparing [`jQuery.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) performance to `eval()`

Answer (score 0):

with the new Function you avoid eval();

```
var mydbfunction=new Function('here the function string');
mydbfunction();
```

this executes the function directly

```
(new Function('here the function string'))()
```

Comment: `new Function` is basically an alias for `eval`. Though, logically it may have a bit better performance.

Comment: No, they are not the same.

eval() evaluates a string as a JavaScript expression within the current execution scope and can access local variables.
new Function() parses the JavaScript code stored in a string into a function object, which can then be called. It cannot access local variables because the code runs in a separate scope.

Comment: Yes, I meant that both evaluate strings of code. Sure thing, the `Function` constructor is way more specific than the generic `eval`.

Comment: thats why i posted new Function .. based on "Is there any other way to call a javascript function stored in mongodb from node js . other than db.eval() " eval is evil , new function not. thats the point

Comment: Also as you've said, the `Function` constructor evaluates the function in the global scope unlike `eval` that can access local variables so it is a nice note. My first comment was that string of code evaluation most often has performance issues and both ways suffer serious security issues. Nevertheless, your answer is valid for the question I believe (though I'm not sure whether `db.eval()` actually means the same as JS's native `eval`..)

Comment: if we talk about a javascript code stored as string the new Function is the most secure way to evaluate the function... i don't know other methods.i use it sometimes with json passing a base64 encoded function and use (new Function(atob('base64')))() to launch it. i use that because eval can access at the other local variables.

Comment: Yes, I meant that it has security issues as functions evaluated through the Function constructor still have full access to all global variables, but never mind it, security is off-topic to the question apparently.

Answer (score 0):

The logical answer is no, not if you wish to evaluate from within MongoDB. This is due to the way that `eval` is actually extended and manipulated within the JavaScript engine implementation in MongoDB.

Instead you should avoid `eval`. Most likely you have coded your application in such manner that makes use of these stored JavaScript functions as though they are stored procedures. That is not the case, they are not stored procedures and definitely should not be used application side if at all possible.

That being said storing JavaScript isn really useful for Map Reduces who use common code. You can just include the saved code in the `system.js` collection and jobs a good'un.